# Rotating an object to face a certain point, but only on one axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles

I have objects that I want to rotate towards a collision point, but only on the Y-axis. Here's what I mean:

1. The arrows show which direction the balls hit the pins.
   [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAecU.png)
2. The object rotates on it's Y-axis to face the collision point.
   [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdZBP.png)

I suspect what I need is to convert the Vector3 of the collision point into rotational degrees, that can then be plugged into the object's Y axis. I have no idea how to do this, or if it's even possible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use Unity's [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function like this:

```
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(Target.position.x, transform.position.y, Target.position.z));
```

Comment: `Light.transform.LookAt(new Vector3(0, point.y, 0));` I tried this. Didn't work. [Result](https://imgur.com/9YVVHXF)

Comment: The thing is if you need to rotate about y axis, you should get the x and z coordinates of your point, not the y

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong then? I'm trying to change the rotation of the Y. I guess that's not exactly the Y axis? Which Axis would it be? Sorry, I'm not very good at this :T

Comment: Yes exactly, if you want to change the rotation of Y, you must look at the x and z coordinates of your target